Upon the death of a malevolent politician, is it permissible to say, "Alhamdulillah?"
We have a political party that is cruel, anti-Muslim, and dictatorial, and when one of its leaders dies, people say alhamdulillah. I want to know if saying "alhamdulillah" is appropriate in this situation. Since most people don't like them at all, and people are afraid to speak out because they use law enforcement forces against common people,
